# Array Formulas - Multiple IF scenarios / Difference between Dates

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas

Here's what I'm struggling with.

I need an arrayformula for the following Google Sheet -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TcB6MFuOC8EChpZEaJeydw8dfyp6C6EntGqSPGzIc5s/edit?usp=sharing

Using my Raw Data sheet, I am trying to have a column CA show the total # of days between Column BN - Column BE BUT only for rows containing Purch in Column K & ONLY when Closed as a date
. I also need it to expand populate for the the whole column CA and to remove blanks.

This is because I am having automated data feed into the spreadsheet via Zapier. Which is also why I need an Array Function so the column doesn't get wiped out in Column CA cells when fresh data gets inputted.

I know this is way off, but this is about as far as I've gotten since I can't find any tutorials about this.

```
=ArrayFormula(if($K1:$K="Purch")*((MINUS{$BN,$BE)))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is progress. I actually just realized I need to limit it to only when Column BN has a closed date. Is that possible? I'm using your second formula and a still getting Refi's rather then Purchases. Do i need to add a statement like: if($K1:K="Purch"

Comment: YOU'RE A LEGEND.  Here is what I used, and this works like a charm =arrayformula({"Avg Closed Days";if(BN2:BN<>"",if($K2:$K="Purch",BN2:BN-BE2:BE,),)})

Answer (score 1):

Try this in cell `CA2`:

`=arrayformula(if(BN2:BN<>"",if(K2:K<>"",BN2:BN-BE2:BE,),))`

or this in cell `CA1` (keeping `CA2:CA` blank):

`=arrayformula({"Avg Closed Days";if(BN2:BN<>"",if(K2:K<>"",BN2:BN-BE2:BE,),)})`

If you only need to evaluate when `BN` has a value, use this:

`=arrayformula({"Avg Closed Days";if(BN2:BN<>"",BN2:BN-BE2:BE,)})`

If it helps, please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :-)

Comment: Thank you! This is progress. I actually just realized I need to limit it to only when Column BN has a closed date. Is that possible?